# Jquery each loop, get then wait for click

Tags: jquery

I am really struggling with ideas on how to get this to work (or even if it is possible) but what I need to do is inside an each loop:

Start of each loop
Change source of iframe
Wait for frame to load
Run a get which modifies some on page content
Then wait for user to click one of 2 buttons
Next item in loop

Is that possible with jquery? So far I have:

```
$.each(arr, function (index, value) {

var url = this.url;
$('#frameid').attr('src',url);
//need to wait for iframe to finish loading here
$.get("ajax.php", {action:'findfields',url:url}, function(result){
    //do some stuff which I already have working
});
//wait for button click and then next in loop

});
```

Comment: Ajax is asynchronous, so by the time the first $.get request is finished, the loop has probably long since finished aswell. You can't really wait for a click either, so you probably want to do this another way, like say with a function that iterates to the next array value etc.

Comment: Just to be clear, do you also want the ajax to have finished as well before the user is allowed to click the button and go to the next iteration?

Comment: Asad yep Ajax does some stuff to the contents of the iframe then a button click should trigger the next iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

A tentative solution is to simply bind the rest of your code to a load handler, and use function recursion for iteration.

```
var arr = [...];
var index = 0;

function iterate() {
    var url = this.url;
    $('#frameid').attr('src',url);
    $('#frameid').unbind("load");
    $('#somebutton').unbind("click");

    //need to wait for iframe to finish loading here
    $('#frameid').on("load",function(){
        $.get("ajax.php", {action:'findfields',url:url}, function(result){
            //do some stuff which I already have working
            $("#somebutton").click(iterate);
        });
    });
    index++;
});
```

Comment: Thanks a million. I didn't use your solution but I totally didn't think about referencing the array by key instead of looping via each. It all fell into place after that!